# Prestashop 1.6: Right route, but URI has extra chars

Tags: php, apache, nginx, routes, prestashop

Have such URL:

```
http://somehost.com/41-some-product
```

If I write something in products it will be ok, but it's a wrong behavior! URLs like

```
 http://somehost.com/41-someAbrakadabra-product
```

still ok while I do not change id or remove dash which after id.  So can I fix it?

**UPDATE:**

I described the problem in a wrong way. I need to redirect in this page with normally URI or have response with 404 which say that such page doesn't exist. The second way is more comfortable.

Comment: Hello. I yet don't understad your problem. Could you please write more clearly?

Comment: When I have request_uri **/41-someAbrakadabra-product** I still have access to this page - but its wrong behaviour!  I want or redirect or 404. 
So I need accessing to this page only by right way: **/41-some-product**

Comment: Adittional suggestion added in my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Friendly URL is set initially acordding to product name, just removing invalid URL chars. Then URL did not change until you change Friendly URL value in SEO tab on product edition backoffice screen. Check this value to write the URL you want for your product.

Go to menu Preferences -> SEO & URLs and disable Friendly URL. Save changes and then enable it again. This will regenerate your `htaccess file` in case of and old configuration is affecting your shop.

Good luck.

Comment: I have a nginx server for my local host. So recreate apache htaccess doesn't give anything.
For all what I found in htaccess there is interest in such lines:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]`
Can you explain how to convert it to nginx and is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The operation respects the rules of PrestaShop. To modify them creates /override/class/dispacher.php
and enter this changing "product_rule":

```
class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{
public $default_routes = array(
    'category_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'category',
        'rule' =>        '{id}-{rewrite}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_category'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    'supplier_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'supplier',
        'rule' =>        '{id}__{rewrite}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_supplier'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    'manufacturer_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'manufacturer',
        'rule' =>        '{id}_{rewrite}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_manufacturer'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    'cms_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'cms',
        'rule' =>        'content/{id}-{rewrite}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_cms'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    'cms_category_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'cms',
        'rule' =>        'content/category/{id}-{rewrite}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_cms_category'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    'module' => array(
        'controller' =>    null,
        'rule' =>        'module/{module}{/:controller}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'module' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'module'),
            'controller' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9_-]+', 'param' => 'controller'),
        ),
        'params' => array(
            'fc' => 'module',
        ),
    ),
    'product_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'product',
        'rule' =>        '{category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_product'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'ean13' =>        array('regexp' => '[0-9\pL]*'),
            'category' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'categories' =>        array('regexp' => '[/_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'reference' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'manufacturer' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'supplier' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'price' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9\.,]*'),
            'tags' =>            array('regexp' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
    /* Must be after the product and category rules in order to avoid conflict */
    'layered_rule' => array(
        'controller' =>    'category',
        'rule' =>        '{id}-{rewrite}{/:selected_filters}',
        'keywords' => array(
            'id' =>            array('regexp' => '[0-9]+', 'param' => 'id_category'),
            /* Selected filters is used by the module blocklayered */
            'selected_filters' =>    array('regexp' => '.*', 'param' => 'selected_filters'),
            'rewrite' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9\pL\pS-]*'),
            'meta_keywords' =>    array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
            'meta_title' =>        array('regexp' => '[_a-zA-Z0-9-\pL]*'),
        ),
    ),
);
}
```

delete cache/class_index.php

Comment: Could you explain with some example according to my update in question?